# is it possible to draw on HWND created by another process?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I am creating window inside my program, then sending HWND of this window to another application. Will drawing on window's HDC be valid for another process?

Comment: See [Thread affinity of user interface objects, part 1: Window handles](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20051010-09/?p=33843) and [Thread affinity of user interface objects, part 2: Device contexts](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20051011-10/?p=33823).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows are owned by other windows, not by processes. You can draw to any HWND on your desktop (at least if the window has the same integrity -- I'm not sure what happens if they don't).

Web browsers that host plug-ins or tabs in a separate process generally make use of this functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you can do this.